# how to remove environment variables set for QSTK?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, environment

I am new to Ubuntu, and I'm having trouble with the terminal application.  Every time I open it this message appears:

```
"bash: /home/xxxxx/.bashrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/xxxxx/.bashrc: line 1: `source QSTK/local.sh# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.'"
```

How can I remove or delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your favorite editor, for example gedit (Super key gedit Enter). Then open /home/xxxxx/.bashrc using the File menu. Delete that first line. Save the file. Now, start up a new terminal window and see if the problem is gone.

Comment: Thanx a ton Gary.